# Print screen with GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, printing, report

I want to print a html page generated by GWT. I am using Window.print().

But when print is invoked only one page is printed.

Is there a way to print all pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to print complete page by creating new window and adding inner html of current page to it and then executing print on it.

A class which provides the same functionality is shared at google code. 
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-print-it/

Comment: Can you share more info about how you've solved this problem. I'm new to gwt and especially javascript, and I would like to try this solution of yours with creating new window and printing it. Can you share at least basic steps in code?

Answer (score 0):

> But when print is invoked only one page is printed.

Are you sure that this is a GWT's problem? The problem maybe  is in browser or in printer's configuration. Try to check this options.

Comment: I tried across browsers (ie, gecko, chrome) and also tried printing with adobe and xps document writers.

Comment: Ok, so if I understood correct somehow print passes to browser only part of needed content. Then you should check if page generated correctly.

Comment: page looks pretty much well rendered on browser. Does it has to do with Scroll Bars?

Comment: Ok, and without Window.print() but with Ctrl+P does it prints normal ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not GWT's problem. Inspect your css styles for noprint styles. For example you can look here:
http://www.killersites.com/articles/newsletterArchive/Newsletter_Nov3_2003.htm